# Можно ли в дочернем классе обращаться к приватной переменной родителя через super?

Tags: java

вопрос такой. На этом [сайте](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/extends.php)

прочитал такое:

> При вызове метода super() с нужными аргументами, мы фактически
>   вызываем конструктор Box, который инициализирует переменные width,
>   height и depth, используя переданные ему значения соответствующих
>   параметров. Вам остаётся инициализировать только своё добавленное
>   значение weight. При необходимости вы можете сделать теперь переменные
>   класса Box закрытыми. Проставьте у полей класса Box модификатор
>   private и убедитесь, что вы можете обращаться к ним без проблем.
>
> У суперкласса могут быть несколько перегруженных версий конструкторов,
>   поэтому можно вызывать метод super() с разными параметрами. Программа
>   выполнит тот конструктор, который соответствует указанным аргументам.
>
> Вторая форма ключевого слова super действует подобно ключевому слову
>   this, только при этом мы всегда ссылаемся на суперкласс подкласса, в
>   котором она использована. Общая форма имеет следующий вид:
>
> super.член Здесь член может быть методом либо переменной экземпляра.
>
> Подобная форма подходит в тех случаях, когда имена членов подкласса
>   скрывают члены суперкласса с такими же именами.

и приводится такой код

```
class A {
    int i;
}

// наследуемся от класса A
class B extends A {
    int i; // имя переменной совпадает и скрывает переменную i в классе A

    B(int a, int b) {
        super.i = a; // обращаемся к переменной i из класса A
        i = b; // обращаемся к переменной i из класса B
    }

    void show() {
        System.out.println("i из суперкласса: " + super.i);
        System.out.println("i в подклассе: " + i);
    }
}


class MainActivity {
    B subClass = new B(1, 2);
    subClass.show();
}
```

В результате мы должны увидеть:

> i из суперкласса: 1 i в подклассе: 2

Вопрос такой, как вы думаете автор ошибся или я не догоняю? он пишит вот тут

> Проставьте у полей класса Box модификатор private и убедитесь, что вы
>   можете обращаться к ним без проблем.

но в коде у себя не ставит  `private`  для `i`
Я пробую на своем примере у меня компилятор ругается, что нельзя в дочернем классе через супер обращаться к приватной переменной. Что скажите как правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по всему, на сайте опечатка или ошибка перевода. Скорее всего, имелось в виду, что вы можете получить доступ через `super.`, если поле помечено как `public` (или `protected`). (И напрямую, если при этом ваш порождённый класс не перекрывает это имя.)

Comment: Вы уверены что по умолчанию оно приватное а не package? и как тогда мне установить переменной модификатор доступа package?

Comment: @ip696: Хм. Сейчас перепроверю.

Comment: @ip696: Вы правы, сейчас исправлю ответ.

Comment: (И напрямую, если при этом ваш порождённый класс не перекрывает это имя.) вот тут не понял. напрмер в моем случае ничего не перекрывает и я все равно не могу получить доступ. тоесть у меня в родителе есть приватная переменная name  и в потомке нет переменной с таким именем. то я могу обратиться к ней из потомка?

Comment: Как я понимал, то через супер я могу обратиться к public  и  protected. перое если мне все равно видна она в других класах или нет, второе если я хочу чтобы видна была только в потомке. Но статья сбила с толку. спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @ip696:  Исправил ответ. В порождённом классе имя `i` обозначает поле порождённого класса. Если вы переименуете это в `j`, то к `i` можно будет обращаться и без `super`.

Comment: "то к i можно будет обращаться и без super" в том случае если  i  не  private я правильно вас понял?

Comment: @ip696: Именно так. Обращаться можно только если package private (из этого package), public или protected (только из потомков). При этом если имя перекрыто, то нужно добавлять `super.`.

Answer (score 2):

Я не имел дело с Java, но метод управления доступом `private` в ООП-языках означает, что только сам класс имеет доступ к собственным членам класса, помеченных этим спецификатором.

В той цитате, которую вы привели, автор скорей всего имеет в виду, что при вызове метода `super()`  вы вызываете конструктор супер-класса, а он имеет доступ к собственным членам класса. Поэтому вызывая этот метод из конструктора производного класса, вы тем самым можете инициализировать приватные члены супер-класса. То есть вы делегируете работу по инициализации приватных членов супер-класса собственному конструктору супер-класса, который, естественно, имеет доступ ко всем членам своего класса. В результате работа конструктора производного класса разбивается на две части. Сначала он делегирует работу по инициализации членов супер-класса конструктору супер-класса, а затем сам инициализирует члены собственного класса и при этом может также изменять защищенные или открытые члены супер-класса.

Comment: я тоже так понял. но сбило с толку предложение "Проставьте у полей класса Box модификатор private и убедитесь, что вы можете обращаться к ним без проблем."

Comment: @ip696 Все правильно. В конструкторе производного класса вы можете делегировать работу по инициализации приватных членов супер-класса конструктору супер-класса.